# Can you explain this test cases of this program of codechef?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve this question of the current ongoing questionof september challenge:http://www.codechef.com/SEPT14/problems/FACTORIZ
**I don't want any solution to this question** just want to understand the question.Basically what it says is this:

```
You are given an integer N, you need to find M positive integers A1, A2, A3, ..., AM, so that A1*A2*A3*...*AM would be equal to N. You should maximize the number M.
Input

The first line of the input contains the integer T, denoting the number of the test cases.

Then T lines follow, each one is describing a single test case and contains a single positive integer N.
Output

For each test case, output the integer M on the first line of the testcases' output. Then, output M lines, where the i-th should contain the number Ai. Ai should be a positive integer, greater than 1.
Input:
4
100
111
1000
48598496894

Output: 
2
10
10
2
37
3
2
10
100
1
48598496894
```

Can someone just explain the test cases?I mean that if we want to maximize the M then shouldn't the answer of 1st test case be 4 (2*2*5*5)?Similarly for the second and third case?What
exactly does the problem is trying to say?I tried to publish the comment on the codechef question but was unable to get any answer?**Pardon me if the question doesn't meet the criteria of SO.**

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the challenge problem, "You should maximize the number M" really means "Make M as large as you can; that's how you increase your score". Any valid partial factorization is accepted.

Comment: are you sure about this as one solution for each test case can be the number which the user inputing?

Comment: @user3851486 Yes, in general there are many acceptable outputs, some better than others.